# jquery-toggles setting state without triggering on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, togglebutton

I'm using the jquery-toggles plugin from simon tabor https://github.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles and need to be able to set the state of the toggle WITHOUT triggering the on toggle event.

Is that possible? If not, is it possible to remove and re-add the toggle using jquery (and set the initial state as needed).

Comment: on: true, // is the toggle ON on init - does this trigger a change event?

Comment: Are you saying pass on:true as the parameter?  Not sure, but passing just true will trigger the on toggle event

Comment: ggzone: no, I'm not talking about the time of creation, rather changing the displayed state LATER, without triggering a toggle event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not possible.  I added to code to create this feature and posted to Git.  New capability is now available in plugin

Comment: It would be great if you could add a few lines to this answer demonstrating the use of this new feature. This would increase the helpfullness of this SO answer dramatically!